# how to add non failing lintr checks in tic.R

Tags: r, lintr

I would like to add non failing `lintr` checks to my (TravisCI-based) CI via [`tic`](https://ropenscilabs.github.io/tic/index.html).

(Initially I implemented the [`testthat` approach](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr#testthat) but it is too bothersome for development.)

The `lintr` documentation provides an [example for `.travis.yml`](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr#non-failing-lints)

```
after_success:
  - R CMD INSTALL $PKG_TARBALL
  - Rscript -e 'lintr::lint_package()'
```

Which I (naively) implemented in my `tic.R` as

```
# run lintr after successful CI build
get_stage("after_success") %>%
  add_code_step(lintr::lint_package())
```

but this is NOT working and lintr-bot is not commenting [on my PR](https://github.com/euctrl-pru/trrrj/pull/8) unlike it was with the `testthat` approach.

I guess the problem is in the missing implementation in `tic.R` of

```
  - R CMD INSTALL $PKG_TARBALL
```

I have no idea about how to do that if it is indeed the issue, so any hints/helps is highly appreciated and welcome!